# How to pass function to disable dates

Tags: angular, typescript, flatpickr

I'm using fatpickr with the angular wrap https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-flatpickr

StackBlitz with the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npep74

**Objective:** I want to make Saturdays and Sundays appear disabled (The next step is that holidays cannot be selected either)

**Problem:** I can't find the explanation of how to do it with this angular wrap and doing it like the original flatpickr documentation doesn't work

Official documentation says it should be like this:

```
 "disable": [
        function(date) {
            // return true to disable
            return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

        }
    ],
```

Wrapper documentation doesnt say anything

**What have I tried ?:**

HTML:

```
<input
               type="text"
               mwlFlatpickr
               [altInput]="true"
               dateFormat="Z"
               [(ngModel)]="desiredDate"
               [disable]="[disabledDay(date)]">
```

TS:

```
disabledDay(date) {
    console.log(date); // <--- on this point date is undefined
    return true;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made mistake in your code, your not suppose to pass the function`s execution your suppose to pass a function definition

instead of

```
<input
               type="text"
               mwlFlatpickr
               [altInput]="true"
               dateFormat="Z"
               [(ngModel)]="desiredDate"
               [disable]="[disabledDay(date)]">
```

change to

```
<input
               type="text"
               mwlFlatpickr
               [altInput]="true"
               dateFormat="Z"
               [(ngModel)]="desiredDate"
               [disable]="[disabledDay]">
```

I forked your blitz checkout the example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7r7rj

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation state: the `[disable]` directive will take an array of dates that you want to disable.

For example:

By function that return true false (which take in a Date object as default argument), and it trigger for every date loaded into the UI calendar:

```
 [disable] = "[functionReturnBool]"

//In the ts:
 functionReturnBool(date){
   //Disable July:
   return date.getMonth() === 6 // july index is 6
 }
```

By range:

```
 [disable] = "[{from: '2025-04-01',
                to: '2025-05-01'},
               {from: '2025-09-01',
                to: '2025-12-01'}]";
```

By specific date:

```
 [disable] = "['2025-03-30', '2025-05-21']"
```

Or combine all of them:

```
 [disable] = "[functionReturnBool, new Date(2019,6,24), '2019-07-25', {from: '2019-07-01', to: '2019-07-08'}]"
```